# DataGridView won't repaint itself when updated from another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, datagridview

I have a problem updating `DataGridView` from another thread. Let me explain. When user clicks a button on a form I need to populate the grid with some rows. This process takes some time, so I'm doing it in a separate thread. Before starting the thread I set `DataGridView.Enabled` property to `false`, to prevent user from editing items while they are being added, and just before the working thread ends I set `Enabled` back to `true`.

The problem is `DataGridView` won't update its contents correctly if scrollbars need to be shown. I'll illustrate this with a screenshot:

[image: partially drawn row]

As you can see, the last visible row is partially drawn and the `DataGridView` won't scroll down. If I resize the grid, making it to repaint itself, all rows appear normally.

Here is some code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] fileNames = new string[] { "file1", "file2", "file3" };
        Thread AddFilesToListThread = new Thread(ThreadProcAddRowsToGrid);
        dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
        AddFilesToListThread.Start(fileNames);
    }

    delegate void EmptyDelegate();

    private void ThreadProcAddRowsToGrid(object fileNames)
    {
        string[] files = (string[])fileNames;
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            EmptyDelegate func = delegate
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(file);
            };
            this.Invoke(func);
        }

        EmptyDelegate func1 = delegate
        {
            dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
        };
        this.BeginInvoke(func1);
    }
```

I've also notices that only `Enabled` property causes this strange behaviour. Changing, for example, `BackgroundColor` works fine.

Could you help me see where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `DataGridView.Refresh()`

Maybe setting the readonly property instead of dataGridView1.Enabled = true;?

Alternatively, I think this may be solved by separating your data from the UI.

It looks to me like this is a simplified example for SO here but if you can I would suggest replacing the equivalent line;

> dataGridView1.Rows.Add(file);

with

```
DataTable table = getData(); //In your snippet (file)
BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = table
dataGridView1.Datasource = source;
```

Then you can also refresh the data using ResetBindings on the BindingSource;

```
table = getData();; //Update your data object
source.ResetBindings(false);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried putting a `Refresh()` after enabling the grid, but it won't help.

Comment: Updated with possible alternative that I employ which seems to help me

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I'd like to point out that without `Enabled` property changes everything works fine.

Comment: Hm well the above has helped me greatly even just for clarity in the code. Maybe setting the readonly property instead of `dataGridView1.Enabled = true;`?

Comment: `ReadOnly` works fine. The drawback is I have some readonly rows in the grid and after setting `ReadOnly = false` for the grid I'll have to look through all the rows and set `ReadOnly = true` for them.

Comment: Hm I see your point "I haven't tried it yet", have you now tried my `BindingSource` suggestion?

Comment: unfortunately not. Some other issues appeared that needed my attention, so as for now I've come up with the following workaround - `dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None; dataGridView.Enabled = true; dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;` I'll post here when I try your solution.